# How to render object inside of an array in object in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to render the data below in react.

```
        const fakeData = {
            201907: {
                15: [{
                    yearMonthKey: '201907',
                    dayKey: '15',
                    startDate: '2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900',
                    title: 'testProgrma',
                    time: '04:29 ~ 04:29',
                    imageUrl: [faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false)], 
                    firstCome: 10
                },
                {
                    yearMonthKey: '201907',
                    dayKey: '15',
                    startDate: '2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900',
                    title: 'testProgrma123132',
                    time: '04:29 ~ 04:29',
                    imageUrl: [faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false)], 
                    firstCome: 10
                }],
                16: [{
                        yearMonthKey: '201907',
                        dayKey: '16',
                        startDate: '2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900',
                        title: 'testProgrma',
                        time: '04:29 ~ 04:29',
                        imageUrl: [faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false)], 
                        firstCome: 10
                    }]
            },
                201908: {
                    17: [{
                        yearMonthKey: '201908',
                        dayKey: '17',
                        startDate: '2019-08-15 00:00:00+0900',
                        title: 'testProgrma',
                        time: '04:29 ~ 04:29',
                        imageUrl: [faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false), faker.image.imageUrl(612, 477, undefined, true, false)], 
                        firstCome: 10
                    }]
                }
        }
```

fakeData contains two big arrays(201907, 201908) and each object, other object are nested inside(15, 16, 17). and each nested objects hold arrays as value.

But here is the problem.

components must be rendered as below.

```
201907
  ㅣ
   - 15
     ㅣ
      - title:'testProgrma',
      - title:'testProgrma123132'
   - 16
     ㅣ
      - title: 'testProgrma'
201908
  ㅣ
   - 17
     ㅣ
      - title: 'testProgrma'
```

It is deeply nested and also bind them according to there yearMonthKey and dayKey.

Answer (score 0):

React won't let object to render. Hence before looping try to build array.

```
    let newArray = []

    for(let j in fakeData){
       for(let i in j){
       newArray.push(i)
    }
    }

console.log(newArray)
```

then render newArray with .map()